# in an MVC php program, where is it best to implement final save tasks?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am wondering where in the program (model or controller) is it standard practice to implement final tasks before saving an object.

For example, I have might have a blog post called $post, which has two properties: $post->text and $post->userId

Whenever a different user edits the post, I want to send the posts owner a notification (the logic for sending the notification is already complete)

But should I be sending the notification in the controller of my program when the model confirms that the edit has been saved? Or should the notification be sent at model level? Or is it subjective depending on how rigid the notification process will be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal situation, you could hook it up on an event. Say you would send a notification to a user based on a save action, this save could trigger the event: "POST_EDITED". You could than make a listener that listens to that event and sends/saves the notification for that user.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

Comment: +1 to the event. This also allows other modules/helpers to listen in on it and act accordingly, rather than hardcoding in the function.